# The problem of changing multiple of 3 to red using jquery on the presented screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

Only jquery script should be used to mark the number of multiples of 3 in red.

Each number is made up of <table>.
I made the code below, but there's an error.

```
$(function(){
    $("#Q2_1").find(function(){     
    var num = $("#Q2_1").val();
        num = Number(num) + 1;
        return num % 3 == 0;
        
    });
    .css({"color":"#f00"});
});
```

Please advise me what the problem is.
Or can you give me a similar but simple example?

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser? `.css({"color":"#f00"});` isn't being applied to anything.

Comment: `.find()` doesn't take a function argument. The argument to `.find()` is a selector. I think you meant `.filter()`

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to use `.filter()` with an ID selector, since there can only be one match. You should be filtering the `<td>` elements in the table.

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to the number?

Comment: `.val()` is for inputs. Use `.text()` to get the contents of a table cell.

Comment: Since the table is made up of an array, I added 1 because I thought that in order to change each character type to a numeric type, I needed to know the index of the array to get the characters in each array.
Because the sequence starts with zero.
But on second thought, I don't think I needed to think about the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector that returns all the `td` elements in the table.

Use `filter()` to restrict this based on a condition.

The condition should get the text of the element; value is for user inputs.

Get rid of the `;` after the call, so you can append `.css()`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tableid td").filter(function() {
        let num = Number(this.innerText);
        return num % 3 == 0;
    }).css("color", "red");
});
```